# in_array() validation not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So i'm trying to use in_array to call a list back from the database and then i'm checking with those results to see if the field "Title" is present in the array by doing the following.

```
$qGetAllTitles = "SELECT ArticleTitle FROM articles 
                  UNION 
                  SELECT ArticleTitle FROM temp_article";
$rGetAllTitles = mysqli_query($dbc, $qGetAllTitles);
$GetAllTitlesRow = mysqli_fetch_array($rGetAllTitles, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if (in_array($Title, $GetAllTitlesRow['ArticleTitle'])){
        $errors[0] = "The title is already taken by another article, please pick a different title";
    } else {
        $TTL = mysqli_escape_string($dbc, trim($Title));
        $errors[0] = "Title worked";     
    }
```

I'm aware that the strings are case sensitive (and i'm looking how to negate this but that's another unrelated question)

My problem is, when i put an already used article title into the title field (which works, all other checks i use work, just not this one) it still returns "title worked", even though the check shouldn't unless the title is unique.

I've checked the SQL input in phpmyadmin (for my MySQL database) and that works getting all (3) results and the method of fetching the query is reused from elsewhere in my code, which also works, same as the in_array check so i'm really not sure why it's not working.

Comment: debug $Title? maybe you are passing a boolean value to it, or something like that? try do debug $Title and $GetAllTitlesRow['ArticleTitle'] to see what's in.

Comment: are you sure `$GetAllTitlesRow['ArticleTitle']` is an array?

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array returns an array with *one* row.  It does not return an array with all the rows of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns multiple rows but you are *only retrieving data for the first row*. So unless the title matches the first row's title you won't find any duplicates. You need to do one of the following:

1) Loop through the result set and make an array of page titles before using `in_array()`

```
$GetAllTitlesRows = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rGetAllTitles, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $GetAllTitlesRows[] = $row['ArticleTitle'];
}
```

or

2) Just search for any articles using that title right in your query which makes the code a whole lot simpler (recommended). In other words, use a WHERE clause specifically looking for that title in the `ArticleTitle` field. If you get any results you know it is taken.

```
$qGetAllTitles = "SELECT ArticleTitle FROM articles WHERE ArticleTitle = '$Title'
                  UNION 
                  SELECT ArticleTitle FROM temp_article WHERE ArticleTitle = '$Title'";
$rGetAllTitles = mysqli_query($dbc, $qGetAllTitles);

if (mysqli_num_rows($rGetAllTitles) > 0){
    $errors[0] = "The title is already taken by another article, please pick a different title";
}
```

Comment: I can't believe i missed that i could just use a WHERE clause. How dumb. Also, Why am i getting only one row returned from the fetch_array? Surely, even though there's only one column (ArticleTitle), there should still be as many array rows as there are values returned in the query?

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array() only returns one result at a time.

Comment: Oh i see, i should have used while if i wanted to get every result out of the array, but you're right that WHERE is a lot easier. Thanks :)

Comment: Never mind, i'd made an error inputting the code. It's working now, thank you very much :)